# Use .htaccess to transparently manage versions of site depending on extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After reading and trying a lot of tutorials and howtos... I have not found a way to do this using .htaccess ;-P

I have this folder structure:

- **somepath**/mywebPHP_v314/ (incluing many subfolders with php files)
- **somepath**/mywebJS_v007/ (incluing many subfolders with js files)
- **somepath**/mywebCSS_v876/ (incluing many subfolders with css files)
- **somepath**/mywebJPG_v543/ (incluing many subfolders with jpg files)
- **somepath/standardhostingfolder/.htaccess** (Only file at this folder. No subfolders)

I would like to program .htaccess to get this behaviour:

- Depending on the extension of the file, Apache will serve transparently the corresponding file.
- E.g. when visiting www.mywebname.com/products/family/somearchive.php Apache will serve transparently somepath/mywebPHP_v314/products/family/somearchive.php (instead of serving the usual somepath/standardhostingfolder/products/family/somearchive.php)
- e.g. when visiting www.mywebname.com/products/family/foto3.jpg Apache will serve transparently somepath/mywebJPG_v543/products/family/foto3.jpg

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Just for clarifying: "somepath/standardhostingfolder/" is the server's "web root" folder: If I delete somepath/standardhostingfolder/.htaccess: When visiting www.mywebname.com/products/family/foto3.jpg Apache will try to serve naturally somepath/standardhostingfolder/products/family/foto3.jpg .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for .jpg, you can create 3 other rules accordingly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebJPG_v543
RewriteRule (.*) /mywebJPG_v543%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast and right answer!

It worked fine just adding this first line: "RewriteEngine on".


I did not mentioned in my original answer: Would it be possible to have these "version" folders BELOW hostingpath?

(e.g. The image file is at
"/serverdirectory/serversubfolder/mywebJPG_v543/products/family/foto3.jpg"
meanwhile the .htaccess file is at
"/serverdirectory/serversubfolder/originalhostingpath/.htaccess")

Comment: I can't see that that would make any difference. Can you just try and replace in Rule/Cond , instead of `mywebJPG_v543` just put `somepath/mywebJPG_v543`

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, but I could not get it work this way.

Let me explain it in a different way:
If I delete somepath/standardhostingfolder/.htaccess: When visiting www.mywebname.com/products/family/foto3.jpg Apache will try to serve naturally somepath/standardhostingfolder/products/family/foto3.jpg .

My target is to write a somepath/standardhostingfolder/.htaccess so when visiting www.mywebname.com/products/family/foto3.jpg Apache will serve transparently somepath/mywebJPG_v543/products/family/foto3.jpg .

Comment: Do have access to (and can edit) apache .conf files?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly I don't.

The unknown key for me is how to add the needed ../ (or something similar) to access a folder that belongs to another subfolders' branch.

Comment: I don't think that you can go abowe your wwwroot folder just by using .htacccess (and it wouldn't make much sense to allow that on shared hosting)

Comment: Thanks for the information and all your support. 

I will rearrange my folder structure into subfolders of wwwroot folder.